# Align TextField With LinearProgress In React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have an TextField/Autocomplete that I wanted the `loaders/linear progress` to be on the bottom of it when loading. However I don't want it that it will push the `TextField/Autocomplete` to move up when it is there.

How will I put or what is the proper way to fix that the `loader/linear progress` won't force the `TextField/Autocomplete` to move up?

Codesandbox is here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-crect?file=/demo.js)

[image]

```
      <Grid component="div" item xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={12} xs={12}>
        <CategorySelect />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: "0.5rem"
          }}
        >
          <LinearProgress />
        </Box>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option - you can set strict height for the select wrapper. Consider following snippet:

```
<Grid component="div" item xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={6} xs={6}>
  <Box height={50}>
    <CategorySelect />
      <Box marginTop="0.5rem">
        <LinearProgress />
     </Box>
   </Box>
</Grid>

<Grid component="div" item xl={2} lg={2} md={2} sm={6} xs={6}>
  <Box height={50}>
    <ProductSelect />
  </Box>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. but I added it also on the <Buttons> but it doesn't align?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add those two classes:

```
.css-1eo5cwl-MuiGrid-root > .MuiGrid-item {
    padding-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
}
.css-qslnu8 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
    position: absolute;
}
```